# How to put multiple row values as in columns or comma separated values in single column

Tags: sql

I am a non-technical person and just need some analysis done on SQL.

I have a table X with values like:

```
| Row ID | Level |
+--------+-------+
| 1201   |    A  |
| 1202   |    A  |
| 1202   |    B  | 
| 1203   |    A  |
| 1203   |    B  |
| 1203   |    C  |
```

I wanted an output with something like:

```
| Row ID | Level  |
+--------+--------+
|  1201  |  A     |
|  1202  |  A, B  |
|  1203  |  A,B,C |
```

Since the Max values per row id could only be 4 could also live with something like

```
|Row ID        |Level   |Level    |Level    |Level|
+--------------+--------+---------+---------+-----+
|1201          | A      |         |         |     |
|1202          | A      |  B      |         |     |
|1203          | A      |  B      |  C      |     |
```

I am just wondering if the second option is easier to achieve.

Thank you so much for you help!!!

This place has helped me a lot in past with my challenges with SQL.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: **1** "sql" is NOT a useful tag, PLEASE use a tag that tells us which database you are using (this is because "sql" syntax differs between database vendors).  **2** Please edit the question and include anything that you have tried even if it did not work.  **3** for comma separated values in one column you need a `group by` query and a database specific function eg.g str_agg(), listagg() (see point 1) **4** for separate columns per level you need a "pivot query" and there are 000's of examples available of this. This is also database specific in many cases (see point 1 again)

Comment: Why does the row 1202 have the value `A, B` and not `B, A`? Relational rows do not have ordering.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution in standard ISO SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE X ("Row ID" INT, 
                Level CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO X VALUES
(1201, 'A'),
(1202, 'A'),
(1202, 'B'), 
(1203, 'A'),
(1203, 'B'),
(1203, 'C');

WITH
T0 AS (SELECT DISTINCT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "Row ID" ORDER BY Level) AS RN
       FROM   X),
T1 AS (SELECT "Row ID", CAST(Level AS VARCHAR(5000)) AS Levels, RN
       FROM   T0
       WHERE  RN = 1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT T0."Row ID", CONCAT(T1.Levels, ', ', T0.Level), T0.RN
       FROM   T1
              JOIN T0
                 ON T0.RN - 1 = T1.RN AND T0."Row ID" = T1."Row ID")
SELECT "Row ID", Levels
FROM   T1
ORDER  BY "Row ID";
```

Some other solution exists for RDBMS. As an example in Microsoft SQL Server or PostGreSQL you can use the STRING_AGG aggragete function...